# Web API Crashing after deploy on azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure, I use the Azure free edition as benchmark .

I developed a webapi service that is using Blob and DocumentDb as DAL, and the webapi works perfect on my local machine.

In my azure account I open App service and I deploy the webapi on azure (using publish).

When I try to surf to my site using the url that was given by azure I receive the following crash error :

> **An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:8081
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   127.0.0.1:8081**

I checked my project and I didn't find any mention of that port or address!!!

Please help my to understand the source of this problem.

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using asp.net or asp.net core. For sure you have 8081 defined in your web.config or project.json and azure does allow process listening on custom port and hence the error

Are you getting some call stack in the exception? That will help identify the code which is trying to go to 8081

Answer (score 0):

App Service platform execution environment is different from local. All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox. We could get more info about Azure Web App from  Azure [official document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). The following is the snippet from the document.

> Network endpoint listening
>
> The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the **already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443)** TCP ports; applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from the internet.
>   However, applications may create a socket which can listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit they be on the same machine, will fail. See the next topic for additional detail.
>
> Local Address Requests
>
> Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, **127.0.0.1**) and the machine's own IP will **fail**, except if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port.
>
> Rejected connection attempts, such as the following example which attempts to connect to 127.0.0.1:80, from .NET will result in the following exception:
>
> `Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:80`